# How do I connect to an archive node with polkadot.js api?

Tags: polkadot-js

Is there a list of archive nodes for polkadot/kusama/parachains?

I'm trying to fetch all historical events in order to visualize staking rewards for nominators and validators.

Comment: Would love to know the answer to this one too. https://app.subsquid.io/aquarium/archives is an alternative where you can graphql to query data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some public archives here: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-endpoints
But I don't think an external archive is going to cut it for your use case.
Archive nodes do not directly provide all past events, so you have to query all past blocks and then extract the events from them. This is really slow, and if you need it for multiple chains it will take even longer.
There are indexer services which can do this for you like the one @Squirrel linked.

If this is a one off; then you can sync your own archive with `--sync warp --pruning archive` in some minutes which then provides the data faster than an external node.