# Get reward amount in polkadot.js/api

Tags: polkadot-js, kusama, rewards

I want to get reward for specific address in polkadot.js/api.
Especially for kusama.
Is polkadot.js providing such api to get reward for specific validator address?
also for specific block height?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4378/polkadot-js-how-do-i-fetch-all-rewards-paid-to-a-specific-nominator-that-result/4390 ?

Comment: It is much helpful. One question is, how can I access archived node to get all past events?

Comment: Maybe this post is helpful https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4432/234 and the wiki page https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-node-management#basic-node-operations ?

Comment: can you solve the problem? I also want to get reward for specific address in polkadot.js/api.